# Looping through resultings record and getting duplicates in foreach

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

So I am trying what I feel is a simply loop through a record result. My query returns one row of data. I am attempting to simply pull the value of each row from the returning record into a variable called $questions. However, my var $questions when printed out has duplicates in every space. It should read something like Bob|Ted|Joe|Sally and instead it is reading Bob|Bob|Ted|Ted|Joe|Joe|Sally|Sally. Why is the code below running twice in the foreach loop?

```
 while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {   
               $questions.=$value."|";       
        }
}
echo "Questions: ".$questions."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all you need to do:

```
$questions = "";
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)){
    $questions .= $row['fieldName']."|";
}
echo "Questions: ".$questions."<br/>";
```

The foreach() in addition to the while() is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The mssql_fetch_array according to PHP doc:

> In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result
>   array, it also stores the data in associative indices, using the field
>   names as keys.

The result includes a normal array [0...n] with one element for each column, but also an associative array where each value is represented by a key named after the column name.

So if your first column is Id, you could get id from a row in two ways:

```
$id = $row[0];
# or you could do this
$id = $row['Id'];
```

This is why you get each value twice when looping through row.